# How count the number of rows starting from a specified row?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a query problem about retrieving number of rows that the counting will start from the specified row. These are the row values on my MySQL database.

```
John Parker
Tony Graham
Perter Smith
Annabelle Sergio
Kris Pata
Neshren Luca
Paul Pon
Zervich Nuckrav
Allan Paulson
Imanu Hashmarida
Varick Dagovich
Senster Burgsman
Lito Umani
Ramsay Nudillo
```

Now I want to retrieve the first 5 row that will start from `Neshren Luca` so that the `resultset` may look like this:

```
Neshren Luca
Paul Pon
Zervich Nuckrav
Allan Paulson
Imanu Hashmarida
```

How may I do that?

**Note**: I will not try to retrieve the row values base on number of row but base from a specific row value.

Comment: Maybe lookup the definition of column and row first...? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: I think you mean **ROW** s not **COLUMN** s. What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: My bad... I'm still confused with row and columns.
anyway, I updated the question.

Comment: Is that all you have in your table is the one column? What are you `ORDER`ing `BY` to get results in that order?

Comment: @ja ok, by the way, are the records above really column names (*fields*)? or they are rows (*records)?

Comment: @Ic Only 1 column with those values. I want to retrieve the first 5 values from the row with the value `Neshren Luca`

Comment: Did you try using LIMIT statement http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm?

Comment: So what are you using to determine the order you receive rows in - to tell you what is "before" `Neshren Luca` and what is "after" `Neshren Luca`?

Comment: @Ic I am thinking of a code that will start from the value `Neshren Luca` on using WHERE clause if it's possible.

Comment: @JW they are row values from a single column(field).

Comment: You have to define an order first... there's no inherent ordering in a table, which means your question is equivalent to "How do I select one row and 4 other random rows"

Answer (score 2):

This looks **very ugly** but have this a try, this uses *local variable*

```
SET @selectedName := 'Neshren Luca'; -- set the name here
SET @selectRow :=
          (
            SELECT RankNo
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT @rowNum := @rowNum + 1 AS RankNo,
                           a.Names
                    FROM   tableName a, (SELECT @rowNum:= 0) b
                ) x
            WHERE  Names = @selectedName
          );

SELECT Names
FROM
  (
    SELECT @rowNum1 := @rowNum1 + 1 AS RankNo, a.Names
    FROM   tableName a, (SELECT @rowNum1:= 0) b
  ) x
WHERE  RankNo BETWEEN @selectRow AND @selectRow + 4
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26fd2/9)

Answer (score 0):

SQL engine may have some 'natural' row order, but it is not guaranteed. You should have primary key, say ID, then ORDER BY ID, find first ID WHERE your string is. And then select first N items WHERE ID >= that id.

Edit: Or, if your database guarantees natural order, find row id/index and LIMIT/OFFSET by this value. SQLite has built-in natural rowid for each table row, for example.

Comment: I will try this logic. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the above select statement will work fine for that..other wise you have to do other way but it will bit lengthy..that..
-> You have to get the above records into a cursor
-> Looping through the cursor and getting the records..